# Django: Hide button in template, if user is not super-user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-users

How do you get your template/view to recognize whether or not a logged in user is a super user or not?

There are certain buttons on my forms (in the template) that I want completely hidden if the user is not a super-user

How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Check out [`is_superuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) on the `User` object:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    ...
    <button>...</button>
    ...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

---

**EDIT:** after @mustafa-0x comments

The above assumes that you have `django.core.context_processors.request` included in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting **which isn't the default**.

The [default setting for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py#L207):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
#    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

already includes the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` (and notably doesn't include the `request` context processor) meaning that in most cases you will already have access to `{{ user }}` without the need to add it to your context via the view, or enable the `request` context processor to access the user as above via `{{ request.user }}`

Comment: doesn't that just check if the user has been authenticated? I need to know if they are a super user

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony the code doesn't work and the link is broken... mind explaining why you rejected the edit?

Comment: You changed the meaning. In a template, the `user` object is usually accessible via the `request` - you removed the `request` meaning that the `user` object would need to be added to the view's context which is wasteful when most people will have it on the request anyway. As for the link, you're right, it doesn't work. I've updated it.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I don't think you're correct: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#users

Comment: Yes? What do you want? My example is perfectly valid and I've explained why. The documentation has decided not to use the `request` object that is normally available inherently in the template via context processor and instead make the assumption that you have added the `user` object in the view before rendering the template. I prefer not to make that assumption and use the `request` object. There's no right or wrong so please stop trying to incite an argument

Comment: Sorry for trying to incite an argument; I'm just trying to understand this. I've got a vanilla Django-1.5 setup here, and `request.user` is not in the default context, mind checking this on your setup? :-)

Comment: Ok, searched a bit more. It seems that [`user` is in the default context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth), but [`request` isn't](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request). Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10158892/2036971

Comment: Ok sorry, I understand what you are saying now and you are correct. It's not that they are in the default context but that by default the context processor `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is included in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` settings file meaning you *do* have access to the `user` object (as well as `perms` and `messages`) as they are added transparently. I'm used to always including my own `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` instead of using the default `global_settings.py` values that I didn't realise the default settings. Apologies

Comment: I've updated the answer with an edit to reflect what you're saying

Answer (score 21):

As discussed in the comments, you can use the `User` object that is available in templates automatically:

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
You are logged in as {{user.first_name}}, here are the
<a href="/admin/">admin pages</a> for changing content.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

You can also use `user.is_staff` which might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you try to check on the login html template weather the user is superuser or not you will not be able to do that because at that very instance it will be false you can check it in views.py file that user is super or not and then redirect it where ever you want. 
[you can do some thing like this as you can see in start function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF9yN.png)

Comment: Please do not add code as a link to an image. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57338808/edit) your answer and paste the code as formatted text.