# Django 1.4 - {{ request.user.username}} doesn't render in template

Tags: django, django-templates

In my view, I can print request.user.username, however in the template, {{request.user.username}} does not appear. To make this easy, I removed the logic from the function, and I am importing render_to_response & RequestContext.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

@login_required
@csrf_protect
def form(request):
    print request.user.username
    data = {}
    return render_to_response('form.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My guess is that I have problem with my settings.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'src',
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help-

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id8), authenticated user's object is stored within `user` variable in templates. Mentioned documentation includes the following example:

> When rendering a template `RequestContext`, the currently logged-in user, either a `User` instance or an `AnonymousUser` instance, is stored in the template variable `{{ user }}`:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.get_username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @buffer, who dug out this old answer, I have updated it with most recent state. When it was originally written, in less than a month after Django 1.4 (which was released at the end of March 2012), it was correct. But since Django 1.5, proper method to get username is to call [`get_username()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username) on user model instance. This has been added due to ability to swap `User` class (and have custom field as username).

Comment: I can pass a user object to the template, but shouldn't the logged in user be accessible through request? It seems request isn't accessible from the template, but is in the view.

Comment: Well interesting. That is correct - instead of {{request.user.username}} (which I used on previous projects), {{user.username}} works. Thanks for the help @tadeck!

Comment: It's preferable to use `user.get_username` over `user.username` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username

Comment: @buffer: That is correct, but it was added in Django 1.5, while the answer has been written in less than a month after Django 1.4 has been released. Will add proper note.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the documentation for [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors).

If you want `request` to be in your template context, then you need to include `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. It is not there by default.

However as Tadeck pointed out in his answer `user` is already available if you are using the default settings, since `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is part of the default list for `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Brian. That is the piece of information I was missing. Were the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS removed from default projects? I may have just forgotten I added them, but it has been a while.

Comment: @EmilePetrone I don't think the current startproject command creates a settings.py with `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. It might have at one time, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @BrianNeal: I don't want to pass the user to the templates..Is there a way  to disable it permanently?

Comment: @user1050619 Yes, define your own TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and do not include the auth or request processors.