# How to add an admin page item into navigation bar (for superuser)?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Could anybody please tell me how to realize a navigation bar containing among others an item leading to admin page?
It should like this

```
                                                 Home | Faculty | Student | Admin
```

In the following code, it works for all items in the bar, except the 'admin' one:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'faculty' %}">Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'student' %}">Student</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'admin' %}">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the urls file admin is described as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'), ...]
```

I would also appreciate if anyone enlighten me on how to make the 'admin' item visible only for superuser. Thank you very much!

Comment: and for the second question see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065699/1418794)

Comment: @doru Thank you very much, I should better take a course on how to use a search engine instead of django coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'faculty' %}">Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'student' %}">Student</a></li>

        {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'admin' %}">Admin</a></li>
    {% endif %}

</ul>
```

Don't forget to check permissions in the view of url admin too.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps!