# page that only admins can visit

Tags: django

hello I would like to know if we can make a page accessible only to administrators (superuser) I can find nothing in the documentation but I would like my analysis page to be accessible only by superuser without using a boolean in the profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate the view with the [**`@staff_member_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.views.decorators.staff_member_required), for example:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    # …
```

or for class-based views (CBVs), you can make use of a [**`UserPassesTestMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin):

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class StaffMemberRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff

class MyView(StaffMemberRequiredMixin, View):
    # …
```

Answer (score 0):

## my_html_page

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    so your html tags and other data you want to show
{% else %}
    you're not authorized to see the content
{% end %}
```

or also you are able to do such restrictions in the views.py:

```
def view_p(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

it would be better idea to create a decorator or use an existing one, if you want to do this restriction alot,
and another good idea is instead of Http-bad-request, send a better message to the user to explain the reason of considering his/her request as bad.( may return a html page that has the message)
also see this:
[Django: Hide button in template, if user is not super-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065676/django-hide-button-in-template-if-user-is-not-super-user)

Comment: thanks willem and mahdi